# help with writing a monad typeclass (associated type classes?)

Tags: haskell, typeclass, associated-types

I want to write a monad type class which will specify some basic actions for a DSL (domain-specific language) monad.

```
class Monad  => MyDSLMonad  where
    type ExprTyp  :: * -> *
    var :: String -> ExprTyp  α ->  (ExprTyp  α)
```

where `ExprType` indicates the expression type, and `var` will introduce a new variable declaration.

The idea is that I'll have a base monad `Base` implementing `MyDSLMonad`, which maybe just works on things like `Int`'s and `Bool`'s, and then higher-level abstractions will be monad transformers, which can work on higher level types.

However, the implementation for `Base`'s `var` function might rely on the fact that it only works on `Int`'s and `Bool`'s, and require some kind of type class constraint on the `var` function. So, I want something like

```
class Monad  => MyDSLMonad  where
    type ExprTyp  :: * -> *
    class ValidTypes 
    var :: ValidTypes  α => String -> ExprTyp  α ->  (ExprTyp  α)

instance MyDSLMonad Base where
    class ValidTypes Base = MyClass
```

I'm aware `rmonads` do this via some type caseing, but is there a nicer way? Also, I kinda like having monad transformers like `StateT` in the regular monads package ... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no nicer way, yet. Max Bolingbroke is building this in GHC, hopefully it will arrive in 7.4. See https://twitter.com/mbolingbroke, here's an example: http://hpaste.org/50576